# How to disable warnings when compiling C code?

Tags: c, gcc

I am working on 32-bit Fedora 14 system. I'm compiling my source code using `gcc`.

Does anybody know how to disable warnings while compiling c code?

---

**EDIT:** Yes i know. Best thing is to fix those Warnings to avoid any undefined/unknown behavior. But currently here, i have written huge code first time and there are lots of error & warning in first compilation. Here i just want to concentrate on errors first and then i will see warnings.

Comment: The best thing for that is to fix your code so that it doesn't emit any.

Comment: after design i have written code so there are lots of error & warning first i just want to concentrate on error by solving after i will see warning

Comment: @patel jigar warnings are most of the time signs of errors or improper usage of language features.

Comment: when I learned programming, we were told that compiler warnings indicate **severe programming errors** while compiler errors often only point to missing headers, semicolons, typos and stuff. **Do not disable the warnings! Fix their causes!**

Comment: That's only partly correct. Some gcc warnings flag things that are best-practices as warnings and encourage you to write broken, non-portable code in their place. The best example I can think of is a braces warning for `mbstate_t state = { 0 };` which encourages people to use `memset(&state, 0, sizeof state);` instead. The latter probably works, but it's not strictly portable.

Comment: @R.. How is `memset(&state, 0, sizeof state);` not portable?  Requires standard C lib?

Comment: @chux: Because the C standard requires a zero-initialized `mbstate_t` object, and the definition of that type is opaque. If it has any floating point or pointer members, the all-zero-bits representation need not yield the zero value that's required.

Comment: @chux: Imagine for instance an implementation where the null pointer's representation is not all-zero-bits and `mbstate_t` contains a pointer to the next-byte-handler for the current state. All-zero-bits would be interpreted as a non-null pointer (not initial state), but would not be meaningful.

Comment: @R.. "A zero-valued mbstate_t object is (at least) one way to describe an initial conversion state." §7.29.6 3 implies to me that `mbstate_t state = { 0 };` and `memset(&state, 0, sizeof state);` are well defined for the initial state.

Comment: @chux: `(mbstate_t){0}` is a zero-**valued** `mbstate_t`. The result of `memset` is a "zero-**representation**". Whether it's also zero-valued is implementation-specific. An implementation may also allows `mbstate_t` objects that are not zero-valued to represent the initial conversion state, but that too would be implementation-specific and thus *not portable*, which was my whole point.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try to add -w option when compiling

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: That will disable all warnings which I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @celavek: neither do I. Warnings serve a purpose. To OP: Better read them and change your code accordingly to make them go away.

Comment: -w only suppress or inhibit the warning not disabling it

Answer (score 6):

Every body tells use `-Wall` switch with gcc, but you want to disable it. It is not advised, Use debugger to find it.

Linus Torvalds:

> "But it clearly is the only right way. The fact that everybody else does it some other way only means that they are wrong"

Comment: I would not remove `-Wall`, but after `-Wall` you want to add some `-Wno-*` options to disable some of the nuisance and false-positive warnings.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question -- looks like an attempt to comment.

Comment: If the OP wants to disable warnings you tell him how to disable warnings. Then, if you are a nice guy you can suggest that it is not a good practice.

Comment: This doesn't try to answer the question at all... 
Sometimes people don't *want* to do things the way everyone else does them, perhaps for a reason, if you think there's an issue with how they want to do it you should leave a comment, or better yet, provide an actual solution and only *then* add that the solution is not advised and why.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to find the problem. It will prevent you in future looking for errors, which would not have occured, if you fixed the actual one.

But, if you're sure there is no bug or you have assured the problem is caught by your code, place this somewhere in the file (where 177 the number of your warning is):

```
#pragma diag_suppress 177 // supress #177-D function  was declared but never referenced
```

Comment: I tried this in `gcc` and `clang` and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

let say you are getting warning `-Wfoo-bar` try to add compilation flag `-Wno-foo-bar`