# How to ignore all warnings in C

Tags: c

How to ignore all warnings in C by using `#pragma GCC ignore`?

I tried `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"`, but it can ignore a specific kind of error only. I want to ignore all errors.

The solution form this post "[how to disable warning in compiling c code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882336/how-to-disable-warning-in-compiling-c-code)" can ignore a specific kind of error only.

Comment: I am working a big project, I cannot adds -w while compiling. #pragma GCC ignore is my only way..

Comment: why wouldn't the `-w` flag work? that turns off warnings during compilation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to disable warning in compiling c code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882336/how-to-disable-warning-in-compiling-c-code)

Comment: Why would you want to ignore something the compiler is telling you is a problem?  Beware -- that is a gateway to bad things.

Comment: Umm, if you ignore errors, your code isn't gonna build?  If this is for a a large commercial style project, I hope to never come across the product you are building.  Ignoring errors and warnings is about as short-sighteded and closing your eyes so you don't see the on-coming car that's about to hit you.

Comment: To ignore warnings, take no action when they appear ..?

Comment: You ask about ignoring all warnings then you say you want to ignore all **errors**. Which is it? You can ignore all errors by `gcc ... 2>/dev/null`. Ignoring all *errors* is, fortunately, not possible. Can you please update your question to explain exactly what you want to do and why?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: Use "-w" to ignore warnings. You can't ignore errors.

The medium answer: Use "#pragma GCC ignored -Wall" to ignore a wide variety of warnings listed in this link: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas. Use "-w" to ignore all warnings. You can't ignore errors.

The long answer: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html, which has information on all the warning/error options.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a piece of critical code, you should only disable those warnings which actually pop up and only for the region given if you really have to. A good approach is:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversions"

// well commented problematic code
...

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Just replace `conversions` with the appropriate warning. The push/pop will assure you return to the state as before the `ignored` warning. Just embrace the absolute required. If necessary, repeat this, do not feel tempted to embrache more lines, just to safe some writing/copying.

**Warnings are your friends.** Sometimes they tell you things you do not want to hear, but they are well meant and if you respect them, you will improve yourself.